# JavaFX @FXML binding from within Java code

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a custom JavaFX component extending the Tab class:

```
public class MyTab extends Tab implements Initializable {
  @FXML private TextField myInput;
  private final MyDTO dto;

  public MyTab(MyDTO dto) { 
    super(); 
    this.dto = dto; 

    final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/my-tab.xml"));
    fxmlLoader.setResources(MSG.getResourceBundle());
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle res) {
    setText("My Tab");
    myInput.setText(dto.getValue());      // !!!
  }
}
```

With the FXML:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.Tab" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<content>
  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
      <Label id="myLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Text:" />
      <TextField id="myInput" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
    </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</content>
</fx:root>
```

I need to create this objects (custom tabs) dynamically from the java code:

```
final MyTab myTab = new MyTab(new MyDTO(...));
tabPane.getTabs().add(myTab);
```

When I use it like this, the @FXML binding doesn't work and the line

```
myInput.setText(dto.getValue());
```

throws NullPointerException. When the line with the setting of the text from the code is commented, the input is showned, so the problem is only in the binding.

I am using JavaFX 2 for Java 1.7

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: Your code as you posted it doesn't really make sense, because the FXML `<MyTab>` element would invoke a zero-argument constructor on `MyTab`, which doesn't exist. That said, it looks like it should work. Can you create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the null pointer exception?

Comment: You're right, I put the contrustructor with the parameter as I left the pure FXML solution, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is very easy, I just overlooked the mistake in the FXML code:

Should be

```
<TextField fx:id="myInput" ...
```

instead of

```
<TextField id="myInput" ...
```